# xsl:include and xsl:param at Google Chrome, with jQuery transform plugin

Tags: jquery, xslt, jquery-plugins, google-chrome

I've been trying to use XSL with Google Chrome, but with no success.
I read that Chrome have some bugs with XSLT, and one of them is that it doesn't support xsl:include. Bug can be checked here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8441.
After some research I found a new version of the transform plugin by Daer System, and it makes xsl:include work at Chrome.

jQuery Transform plugin can be found from http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Transform

Now my problem is:
I use a default include in some xsl templates, and this include uses a parameter that is passed to the top level one.

So its like i have the **top.xsl** template that declares a [xsl:param name="param" /], and i use this param with the **included.xsl**, that is called by the 1st one with [xsl:include href="included.xsl"] . This works both on Firefox and Internet Explorer, but not on Chrome. I saw a question here on stackoverflow where some guy re-write the webkit fix function from the plugin, but it doesn't work with xsl:param this way.

Does anyone know some way to use [xsl:param] like this in Google Chrome?

Comment: It looks like this is so only when running the transformation through javascript. As you can see, my XML/XSLT driven site works: www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar

Comment: Hi Alejandro, yes, this is by doing javascript transformations. I need to do this via javascript.

Comment: user357812: please explain: how is that link relevant to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem here is that Google Chrome (=Chromium) does not support `xsl:include`**

The lack of this feature is well noted in the Chromium project as raised in ["Issue 8441: XSLTProcessor in JS does not permit xsl:include for http"](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8441). It seems that the problem is caused by some architectural problem in WebKit (the rendering engine used in Chrome). Since this problem originates to WebKit, the bug is marked as WontFix -- the fix will be provided (hopefully) in the future as the original problem in the WebKit is getting resolved.

I see three possible alternatives of how this problem could be resolved for you:

1. Wait until WebKit/Chrome gets a patch that fixes this problem *(potentially takes a long time...)*
2. Create/find a hack that works around this problem for instance by emulating somehow `xsl:include` for Chrome/Webkit *(potentially requires a lot of work / developing a hack)*
3. Try to find a way writing your software in a way that you don't require this specific XSL feature (alternatively run XSL transformation in server-side)

**My recommendation: avoid using xsl:include with xsl:param on client side unless you are willing to give up on cross-browser compatibility**

Comment: Hey jsalonen, thanks for the answer. As the question is from sep, 2010, I managed to solve that by "recompiling" the xsl pages. As I use .net on server side, I made a script that removes the xsl:include and concats the xsl include files inside the ones that calls it.
I'm pretty sure its possible to solve that with javascript, but as you said, it would take a lot of work and a lot of code just to manage that. So I just did that on the server, making it that I can still reuse xsl:templates editing the raw files, and the javascript reading the server generated xsl files.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic I know, but checked back here to see if the issue has been resolved.

I tested again and it has, at least in version 47 of Chrome.  At last you can use xsl:include.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pain, but you can also work around this using a client-side shim that preloads any xsl:import/xsl:includes in the browser.

The following is TypeScript (basically statically typed JavaScript that compiles to JavaScript) and has a few references to interfaces that..uh, I didn't bother removing, but it seems to work in Chrome (not sure about other browsers) and should be enough to get anyone started on a solution.

```
module DD.Render.DOM.XSLT {

export class StandardXSLTDOMTransformerFactory implements IXSLTDOMTransformerFactory {

    constructor(private _domParser:DOMParser, private _document:Document) {
    }

    createTransformerFromPath<T>(xslPath: string, xmlTransformer: IStringTransformer<T>, onSuccess: (transformer: IParameterizedDOMTransformer<T>) => void, onFailure: (e: any) => void): void {
        DD.Util.readXML(
            xslPath,
            (node: Node) => {

                // look up any xsl:import or xsl:includes and pull those in too!
                var onIncludesPreloaded = () => {
                    console.log(node);
                    var transformer = this.createTransformerFromNode(node, xmlTransformer);
                    onSuccess(transformer);
                };
                this.rewriteIncludes(xslPath, node, {}, onIncludesPreloaded, onFailure);
            }, function (e: any) {
                onFailure(e);
            }
        );
    }

    rewriteIncludes(path:string, node: Node, imported: { [_: string]: boolean }, onRewritten:()=>void, onFailure:(e:any)=>void): void {
        var result;
        var element = <Element>node;
        var importNodes = element.querySelectorAll("import,include");
        if (importNodes.length == 0) {
            onRewritten();
            result = false;
        } else {
            var rewrittenNodes = 0;
            // load imports
            for (var i = 0; i < importNodes.length; i++) {
                var importElement = <Element>importNodes.item(i);
                var href = importElement.getAttribute("href");
                // TODO work out relative path
                var relativePath = DD.Util.appendRelativePath(path, href);
                console.log("importing " + href +" + "+path+" -> "+relativePath);
                if (!imported[relativePath]) {
                    var e = importElement;
                    imported[relativePath] = true;
                    DD.Util.readXML(relativePath, (importedStylesheet: Node) => {
                        this.rewriteIncludes(relativePath, importedStylesheet, imported, function () {
                            // replace the import with this node (minus stylesheet container)
                            for (var j = 0; j < importedStylesheet.firstChild.childNodes.length; j++) {
                                var templateNode = importedStylesheet.firstChild.childNodes.item(j);
                                if (templateNode.nodeName.indexOf("template") >= 0) {
                                    e.parentNode.insertBefore(templateNode, e);
                                }
                            }
                            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
                            rewrittenNodes++;
                            if (rewrittenNodes == importNodes.length) {
                                if (onRewritten) {
                                    onRewritten();
                                }
                            }
                        }, onFailure);
                    }, onFailure);
                } else {
                    importElement.parentNode.removeChild(importElement);
                }
            }
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    createTransformerFromNode<T>(xsl: Node, xmlTransformer: IStringTransformer<T>): IParameterizedDOMTransformer<T> {
        var nodeTransformer = new DOMParserDOMTransformer(this._domParser, xmlTransformer);
        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        return new StandardXSLTDOMTransformer<T>(xsltProcessor, nodeTransformer, this._document);
    }

}

} 

module DD.Util {

export function readXML(path: string, onSuccess: (node: Node) => void, onFailure: (e: any) => void) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        onSuccess(xhr.responseXML);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e: ErrorEvent) {
        onFailure(e);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

export function appendRelativePath(originalPath: string, relativePath: string, originalPathIsDirectory?: boolean) {
    if (originalPathIsDirectory == null) {
        originalPathIsDirectory = originalPath.charAt(originalPath.length - 1) == '/';
    }
    if (!originalPathIsDirectory) {
        // remove file imediately
        var lastSlash = originalPath.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (lastSlash >= 0) {
            originalPath = originalPath.substring(0, lastSlash + 1);
        } else {
            originalPath = "";
        }
    }
    var slashIndex = relativePath.indexOf('/');
    if (slashIndex >= 0) {
        var relativeDirectory = relativePath.substring(0, slashIndex + 1);
        var relativeRemainder = relativePath.substring(slashIndex + 1);
        if (relativeDirectory == "../") {
            // trim off a directory on the original path
            if (originalPath.charAt(originalPath.length - 1) == '/') {
                originalPath = originalPath.substring(0, originalPath.length - 1);
            }
            var dirIndex = originalPath.lastIndexOf('/');
            if (dirIndex >= 0) {
                originalPath = originalPath.substring(0, dirIndex + 1);
            } else {
                originalPath = "";
            }
        } else {
            // append to the original path
            if (originalPath.charAt(originalPath.length - 1) != '/') {
                originalPath += '/';
            }
            originalPath += relativeDirectory;
        }
        appendRelativePath(originalPath, relativeRemainder, true);
    } else {
        // append and be done
        if (originalPath.charAt(originalPath.length - 1) != '/') {
            originalPath += '/';
        }            
        return originalPath + relativePath;
    }
}

}
```