# XSL not rendering/acting properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xslt

So, I'm working on updating 10-12 year old code to be Chrome compatable, and I've stalled out already.  For whatever reason, when I input a number and then click the "fillPO" button, it doesn't update anything, and instead places a "null" into the box it should be filling.  This works as intended on Internet Explorer. Is there a general rule to get this to work on chrome?

```
<xsl:template name="control-row">
    <xsl:if test="$orderApprove='true' and $isSuperUser='false' and $archiveView='false' ">
        <td nowrap="true" colspan="10">
            <input type="button" name="servlet" value="Approve" onClick="return approveOrder();">&nbsp;checked orders</input>
            <xsl:if test="/poursxml/OrderedFields/Field='PO'">
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                Fill PO number across orders:&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="genericPO" id = "genericPO" size="15" maxlength="30"/>
                &nbsp;
                <input type="button" value=" Fill PO " onclick="fillPO()"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </td>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This is the fillPO() in javascript.

```
function fillPO()
{
    if(!anySelected())
        alert('Please select an order first.');
    else
    {
        dfa = document.getElementsByName('orderNumber');
        len = dfa.length;
        var ix = 0;
        for(ix=0; ix<len; ix++)
        {
            if(dfa[ix].name == 'orderNumber')
            {
                if(dfa[ix].checked == true)
                {
                    el_id = dfa[ix].id;
                    position = el_id.substring(11);
                    document.getElementById('PONumber' + position).innerHTML = '<input size="15" maxlength="30" type="text" name="PONumber" value="' + document.getElementById('genericPO').getAttribute('value') + '"></input>';
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the chrome debugger? Its really helpful to get more info about what is not working. Firs try to find out which part does not work (xlst, or javavscript).

Comment: This javascript is strange. get all elmements with name "orderNumber" `dfa = document.getElementsByName('orderNumber');` and testing if the are really have the name "orderNumber" `if(dfa[ix].name == 'orderNumber')`

Comment: @hr_117 I was looking at some other stuff on this site and I found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653682/xslinclude-and-xslparam-at-google-chrome-with-jquery-transform-plugin  Seems the problem could be the include statement at the end of my page?  Seems most of the stuff works alright until I have to sumbit.

Comment: It's hard to know what your problem, because there seems to be a lot more code xslt javasctipt and your input xml be involved as your are (can) showing here.  But as I said first step should be to figure out where the problem starts; xslt or javascript. Relating to xsl:include I have never used xsl:include on browser site, so I do not know. The posted javascript and xsl parts seem to be ok.

Comment: @hr_117 Yeah..Im having a hard time figuring out what the problem is too, it works perfect in IE.  I haven't seen any errors pop up in the debugger.  I would add all the code, but there is over 2000 lines of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess: replace `document.getElementById('genericPO').getAttribute('value')` with `document.getElementById('genericPO').value`.

But we really need to see a sample allowing us to reproduce the problem in Chrome.

Comment: A sample of the site actually running?  I've been pouring over it with Chrome debugger but I'm not seeing any exceptions or anything.  Not sure where to look at this point.  I did try your guess, the result was the same though.  Is there any way could shed more light on the situation?  What do you need from me to be able to help more?  Thanks.

Comment: If you have a public URL where we can visit the problem then post it, together with instructions as to which button(s) to click and which controls to check for the right value.

Comment: Also I made a simple test case http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/2013/test2013042301.html and for IE in quirks mode it outputs the value entered in the `input type="text"` control while other browsers like Mozilla or Chrome (correctly) output `null`. I say correctly because `element.getAttribute('value')` is supposed to output the original value of the attribute named `value`, and not the data entered by the user. If you want that use `element.value`. So based on that test case the code `document.getElementById('genericPO').getAttribute('value')` could indeed cause the problem.

Comment: And http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/2013/test2013042302.html with `document.getElementById('inp1').value` fixes the problem. So based on that and with the few lines of code you have presented I still think my suggestion should fix a cross-browser compatibility in your code. Whether it is the one you are looking for is hard to tell, so far we see some XSLT and some Javascript that is called from HTML elements generated by the XSLT but it seems you have not even shown elements accessed by `document.getElementById('PONumber' + position)` or `document.getElementById('genericPO')`.

Comment: I go with this answer and explanation.

Comment: Turns out this was the right answer.  Thanks for the explanation.  Seems to work in IE too.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no obvious problem (at least for me) in your posted code fragments. 
Here some Debug hints (which may help a little bit):

- Consider to have a look to the generated html (perhaps copy and format it) and compare it against the IE generated html. This could be done in the Elements tab of chrome debugger.
- Try to set an breakpoint in the possible not working javascript function.
- If this still does not help. Consider to copy the probably server-sided generated xml. This could be done within the "Network" tab in chrome debugger. Try to reduces the xml and test it offline to find the trouble causing part.
- If debugging doses not work as expected. Add some `console.log("test point");`or `alert()` calls to the javascript.

(.. may be continued ..)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm suffering from a lack of familiarity with the Chrome debugger.  Test point seems like a good idea.