# getElementById not returning proper value (maybe syntax issue?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xslt

I am using XSL to write this page, and when I hit a checkbox it sends the information to my javascript function.  This all works in IE, but Chrome it does not.  The problem is, after I hit the checkbox, the field comes back as "undefined" like so

```
<div id="Part1" value="0-SER-MN">undefined</div>
```

Where it is initially like

```
<div id="Part1" value="0-SER-MN">0-SER-MN</div>
```

My guess would be that the value being returned is "null" but I don't know why?  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

```
        <td colspan="2">
        <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">Part<xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="Part"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="ErrorMessage">
                <input type="hidden" name="partNumber">
                    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="Part"/></xsl:attribute>
                </input>
                <input type="hidden" name="TempKey">
                    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="TempKey"/></xsl:attribute>
                </input>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="./Part"></xsl:value-of>
        </div>      
    </td>
```

SO here is the javascript that is selected with the checkbox

```
     function turnOnOrder(index, tempKey)
 {
    document.getElementById('Part' + index).innerHTML     = '<input type="hidden" name="partNumber" value="' + document.getElementById('Part' + index).value + '"></input>   <input type="hidden" name="TempKey" value="' + tempKey + '"/>' + document.getElementById('Part' + index).value;
        document.getElementById('Location' + index).innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="location" value="' + document.getElementById('Location' + index).value + '"></input> ' + document.getElementById('Location' + index).value;
        document.getElementById('Site' + index).innerHTML     = '<input type="hidden" name="siteCode" value="' + document.getElementById('Site' + index).value + '"></input> ' + document.getElementById('Site' + index).value;
        document.getElementById('PONumber' + index).innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="origPO" value="' + document.getElementById('PONumber' + index).value + '"></input><input size="20" maxlength="20" type="text" name="PONumber" value="' + document.getElementById('PONumber' + index).value + '"></input>';
        document.getElementById('Quantity' + index).innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="OrderQty" value="' + document.getElementById('Quantity' + index).value + '"></input> ' + document.getElementById('Quantity' + index).value;

        if(document.getElementById('viewPrice') == null)
            document.getElementById('Price' + index).innerHTML    = '<input type="hidden" name="Price" value="' + document.getElementById('Price' + index).value + '"></input> ';   
        else
            document.getElementById('Price' + index).innerHTML    = '<input type="hidden" name="Price" value="' + document.getElementById('Price' + index).value + '"></input> ' + document.getElementById('Price' + index).value;

        document.getElementById('UserId' + index).innerHTML   = '<input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="' + document.getElementById('UserId' + index).value + '"></input> ';
        //document.getElementById('InactiveOverride' + index).innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="InactiveOverride" value="' + document.getElementById('InactiveOverride' + index).value + '"/>';
        //document.getElementById('MpqMoqOverride' + index).innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="MpqMoqOverride" value="' + document.getElementById('MpqMoqOverride' + index).value + '"/>';
        document.getElementById('Other' + index).innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="Supplier" value="' + document.getElementById('Supplier' + index).value + '"></input><input type="hidden" name="ICST" value="' + document.getElementById('ICST' + index).value + '"></input><input type="hidden" name="backflush" value="' + document.getElementById('backflush' + index).value + '"></input><input type="hidden" name="Billing" value="' + document.getElementById('Billing' + index).value + '"></input><input type="hidden" name="InactiveOverride" value="' + document.getElementById('InactiveOverride' + index).value + '"/><input type="hidden" name="MpqMoqOverride" value="' + document.getElementById('MpqMoqOverride' + index).value + '"/>';
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an javascript DOM access issue. And has nothing to do with xslt.

The problem is based on the difference between **DOM property** and **html attributes** and the different handling in browsers. 
In most cases using the DOM property (dom-elment.attribute-name) should work. Because the browser synchronize html attribute to DOM property. But this does not happen (in Chrome etc.) for customer attribute (e.g your value attribute at div).

Therefore you should use

```
document.getElementById('Part' + index).getAttribute('value')
```

in replacement for `document.getElementById('Part' + index).value`

This should work in all reasonable modern browsers (e.g IE > 6)

Comment: That worked, but its odd and not sure I understand it.  I had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148571/xsl-not-rendering-acting-properly-in-chrome) before on another page, except it was the reverse of what we just did. Is there a reason why this is?  Thanks for answering my questions, you've been helpful for sure.

Comment: If I remember correctly last time it was reading the changed value of an input field. This will be in the DOM property "elm.value". The getElementById than reads the initial value of the html attribute and will not be changed.